# How to use react-monocle to visualise a react app created by create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I created a react app using `nxp create-react-app`. I want to visualise the component hierarchy of the app, and I found a project called [monocle](https://github.com/team-gryff/react-monocle) that does this.

The monocle tool takes a mandatory parameter which is the "bundle" file. What is this bundle file, and how do I generate this?

Comment: Have you tried running a production build and then providing the output as the extra parameter?

Comment: @lix I can run a production build, but --bundle is a mandatory parameter. Also, do you mean giving the build folder path using -d argument?

Comment: this is what I would guess it could be refereeing to when looking for a bundle argument

Comment: @lix I just tried, and running `monocle -b build/` doesn't work. The discription for -b says 'Path to React bundle file.'